# PHPExcel to XML -- retain styles

Tags: phpexcel

I'm reading an Excel file (.xlsx) and outputting XML with PHP in a manner like this:

```
$cellVal = $objPHPExcel->getSheetByName($Sh)->getCellByColumnAndRow($tCol,$i)->getValue();
echo '<data_text>'.$cellVal.'</data_text>';
etc..
```

Everything is working perfectly, except when there's some styling -- italics, or bold, or both -- in a cell: the styling gets lost. Is there a clever way to retain it?

Things might be easier if it'd be the styling of a whole cell. But what if there's mixed styles?

Comment: You define how your XML is structured, so you say how to store that styling information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the cell's getFormattedValue() method rather than getValue() if you want the number masking.

Other styles such as italic, bold, etc can be returned by method calls to read the styling for a cell; but you need to decide how you're going to store that information in your own XML. For mixed styles, PHPExcel will let you parse the RichText Object that it returns; but again, you need to decide on how it should be stored in your own XML.

Comment: Thank You Mark, getFormattedValue() was not changing things, pointing me to RichText Object was the solution. That directed me to the solution I needed at [http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/77081](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/77081) `if($item->getFont()->getItalic()) {` etc